# Travel from Berlin to Warsaw byplane with Blue Card

Tags: berlin, lost-documents, warsaw, customs-and-immigration

DHL recently lost my passport, and, of course, it's a week before I fly to Warsaw for a wedding :) I have a Blue Card issued in Berlin, where I live and work, which is valid until 05/2022. Otherwise, I have an Israeli ID card, being probably not helpful.

Do you think I can expect problems boarding the flight? Is it just a matter of luck if they ask for my passport?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you are required to have the passport with you as well as the blue card when you cross from Poland back to Germany. That applies no matter how you travel. Your blue card is not, technically, an identity document.

Comment: What did your consulate say? A week should normally be plenty of time for a consulate to issue a short-term emergency passport.

Comment: The blue card is not actually a document, but rather the type of visa you have. If you have a card, that's a _Aufenthaltstitel_ issued under §19a _Aufenthaltsgesetz_. The card as a visa is only valid in conjunction with your passport and the little extra paper that states which kind of field you are allowed to work in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the airline requires you to carry a passport depends on which airline you are flying with and perhaps which airport you are flying from.

I am not sure about Polish law, but German law requires you to *carry* a recognized travel document (passport or EEA national identity card) when crossing its border, both leaving and entering. There is no permanent immigration or id check by the authorities when crossing from Germany to Poland, but random checks do occur.

Answer (score 3):

You should contact your nearest embassy or consulate to replace your passport. I would describe to them the situation, probably they will make it fast. 
Concerning the flight: IMHO, it is just a matter of luck (or maybe of internal rules of the airline) if they ask for the passport. But I wouldn't try to travel without the passport.

Comment: Since they accept German ID cards, and the _Aufenthaltstitel_ looks like a blue-red version of the ID, has an issue date and a photo and the name, chances are they'll allow it for identification. There is no need to go past border controls for an intra-Schengen flight, so it _might_ be alright.

Comment: @simbabque I wouldn't say so.

Comment: Blue Card is is a residence title. "Residents have to possess up to three different documents: a passport from their country of citizenship, their residence permit, and the supplementary sheet (if applicable). Carrying passports and residence cards is compulsory when crossing borders" (Wikipedia). For the flight documentation requirements, one should check the airline terms and conditions.